# Metaio, showing multiple content on camera view

Tags: java, android, metaio

I'm trying to add multiple views when detecting QR code. I need to show one button, one image and one text when QR code is recognized. I use metaio SDK-Template project and for now I'm only able to show one thing at a time.
Can someone please point me in right direction?

Answer (score 1):

when you use metaio for detecting QR codes you're lossing the concept of augmented reality because you are scanning for a QR code and you wont be able to set a 3d model into your target or make visible and enable view components on the UI, if you have concerns about the objective about augmented reality foundamentals check the metaio documentation and examples at dev.metaio.com. Regards